# Retry reading a customer request on socket level

Tags: java, sockets, networking, netty, selector

I'm working on a transport mechanism, where I am supposed to ignore OP_READ events on a socket, if the internal queue is already full.

```
  SelectionKey next = it.next();

  if (next.isReadable()) {
      SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) next.channel();

      if (!innerqueueIsFull()) {
           if (client.read(nextRead) == -1) {
                 break;
           }
      }
   }
```

After writing a response for one of the pending requests, I want to go back and retry reading the data packets on the channel. How can I retry reading the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on a transport mechanism, where I am supposed to ignore OP_READ events on a socket, if the internal queue is already full.

The correct way to do that is to unregister interest in OP_READ for that channel, or for all channels if there is only one internal queue. Then you won't even get the `isReadable()` events on the channel. When the queue clears, re-register OP_READ.

The effect will be to block the affected peers from sending.

> How can I retry reading the request?

You don't have to retry anything this way. Just react to `isReadable()` in the normal way. As a matter of fact you don't have to retry anything your way either, as you never did the read in the first place, so there is nothing to retry.

NB If `client.read()` returns -1 it is utterly bizarre to `break`. You should *close the channel* and *continue.* There's no reason not to process other events just because one client has disconnected.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds perfect. (Btw, the  snippet I posted is just the test code, I don't break when client.read() returns -1)